# Create a matrix of hex color values from an image

Tags: r, colors, pixel

How can I generate a matrix of hex color values of an image, where each element in the matrix represents a pixel in the image? I think that `pixmap` provides the rgb channels for an image in a matrix format, but not the hex values.

Comment: Asking for a recommendation is considered off-topic for SO. If you can please narrow your question to a specific programing problem you are having. This post describes on/off-topic posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Couldn't you generate an RGB matrix and then convert it to hex with `rgb`

Comment: @emilliman5 I probably could, but I guess I'm looking for something more efficient. I'm inexperienced in this area, so maybe just using rbg is better. Also, I'll keep what you said about off-topic questions in mind next time.

Comment: if you want efficiency, go ahead and specify that in your question (e.g., tell us how big your image is; even try out an `rgb()` solution and tell us how much it would need to be sped up to be practical for your needs)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function `grDevices::rgb`.

```
R = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
G = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
B = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)

HEX = grDevices::rgb(R, G, B)
HEX = matrix(HEX, 10 ,10)
```